# Chrome Debugging tutorial appears not do work. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying this Google tutorial to debug my Chrome extension:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html

- I've switched to *developer mode* on the Extensions page
- Installed the *Hello World* extension as advised by the tutorial

Now I'm right clicking the icon of the *Hello World* extension to get the menu.

In this menu (and developer mode on) there is supposed to be an item called  **Inspect popup**, but it's just not there. It's not on any other extension either.

I'm using Chrome V21 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 4):

*The ["Inspect popup"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup) option is back, the answer below is **no longer valid for recent Chrome versions** (~27?).*

> That tutorial is slightly outdated. Indeed, in the past, every browser action button had a menu option called "Inspect popup". When a browser action didn't have an associated popup, the option was still visible, but disabled.
>
> Now, you have to open the popup by clicking on it, then right-click inside the displayed popup and choose the "Inspect Element" option in order to launch a dev tools instance for the popup.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get it.