# Chrome extension - inspect views don't show up

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extension development. I tried to follow the "hello world" debugging tutorial at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html, but I couldn't find the inspect popup menu or inspect views link to open the debugger when I right-click on the "hello world" icon.

I noticed that in my chrome extension tab: chrome://chrome/extensions/, there is an "inspect views" link which enabled me to open a debugger for Google translate extension that I've installed before. However, the "inspect views" link didn't show up for "hello world" extension (source code: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/getstarted.zip).

I have tried to search if someone has a similar problem but I couldn't find one. I'm using Google chrome  21.0.1180.60 for Windows XP.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to open the debugger!

Comment: The shortcut - > ctrl + shift + j, will open the console for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Debugging tutorial appears not do work. What I'm doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767060/chrome-debugging-tutorial-appears-not-do-work-what-im-doing-wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right... Try this:

- Open the ext popup window by clicking on it
- Right-click inside the displayed popup and choose the "Inspect Element" option
- This will launch a dev tools instance for the popup.

For more details: http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/debugging-google-chrome-extensions/