# Chrome app displays blank window and won't do anything

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am at the end of my wits. am developing my first chrome app.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "My App",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
    // Center window on screen.
    var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
    var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
    var width = 1024;
    var height = 768;

    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        id: "myappid",
        bounds: {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            left: Math.round((screenWidth - width) / 2),
            top: Math.round((screenHeight - height) / 2)
        }
    });
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>    
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div id="main" style="position:relative">
        <div id="board" style="position:absolute"></div>
        <div id="div1" style="position:absolute;left:800px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log("inside main");
    // rest of the code hidden
};
```

result of launching the app from extensions menu:

[image]

i click on inspect background:
[image]

and get:
[image]

i click on inspect index.html and get:

[image]

**i am able to open index.html directly in browser and verify it works fine as a stand alone html page - the js executes etc.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the code you have shown is correct.

- Your manifest specifies the background page
- The background page correctly listens for the event, and creates the main app window
- The app window (index.html) appears on screen, and loads `app.js`
- `app.js` waits for the window to load, and logs "inside main" to the *foreground page's * console.

Your Chrome app has a background page, and a foreground page, and so it has two consoles. What you have shown is exactly what I would expect to see, given the code you've posted. The background page's console (which you inspected first) is empty, and the foreground page's console (which you inspected by right-clicking and selecting "inspect element") contains "inside main".

If you wanted to, you could see a message printed to the background page's console by using the callback to `chrome.app.window.create`; something like this:

```
    console.log("Going to create the window");
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        id: "myappid",
        bounds: {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            left: Math.round((screenWidth - width) / 2),
            top: Math.round((screenHeight - height) / 2)
        }
    }, function() {
        console.log("Successfully created the window");
    });
```

That callback should execute before `window.onload` is fired in the foreground window.

Now, there aren't any errors shown in the foreground console, but without knowing what JavaScript, if any, is in this bit:

```
// rest of the code hidden
```

I can't tell what, if anything, should be executing.

Comment: hi, the red error was when i typed location.reload(true). i have edited my question to show screenshot without it. i think when i launch the app, either app.js is not downloaded (first guess) or the event handler never gets called. the console message is only when i clicked on inspect index.html link

Comment: in app.js i do not have any window.open whatsoever

Comment: Ahh, then I misread what the actual error was; sorry. Incidentally, `chrome.runtime.reload()` is a good substitute for `location.reload()`

Comment: I've updated based on that, but the results you are seeing are still correct, given the code that you have posted. Could you explain what you think is *supposed* to be happening, but isn't?

Comment: when index.html is loaded, it is supposed to render the page with UI of the app. all rendering is done in js. if i open index.html using the browser file->open it works. i inserted your code and this code is getting hit: console.log("Successfully created the window"); but sometimes i don't see any link to inspect index.html in the debug menu (as is the case when i am typing this)

Comment: one thing i just noticed (don't know if it helps). the window that is created to show index.html does not seem to respect the width and height passed in bounds. i changed the values, and the window is always the same size.

Comment: I figured it should render the UI, but I can't tell *how* -- is it running immediately? after a timeout? attaching event listeners? waiting for callbacks from Angular.js? Is it trying to look for DOM elements with jQuery? Or loading resources from the network, or the filesystem? It's impossible to guess at this point; all I can tell you is that all of the code that you have actually posted is correct, and appears to be doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: adding link to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11878166/147530 since i don't always see inspect index.html on the debug page. inspecting the DOM of the launched window i see it has al the canvas objects i add dynamically in js, but strangely window is blank. i dynamically load a bunch of images and render them onto canvases + draw lines, none of these are rendering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57365/discussion-between-morpheus-and-ian-clelland).